# Cron job to SCP files in a directory

Tags: cron, scp

Scenario: I need to create a cron job that scans through a directory and scps each file to another machine

- bash script : /home/user/sendFiles.sh
- cron interval : 1 minute
- directory: /home/user/myfiles
- destination: 10.10.10.123

Create the cron job

```
crontab -u user 1 * * * /home/user/sendFiles.sh
```

Create the Script

```bash
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/scp -r user@10.10.10.123:/home/user/myfiles .
#REMOVE FILES AFTER ALL HAVE BEEN SENT
rm -rf *
```

Problem: Not exactly sure if that cron tab is correct or how to scp an entire directory with the cron tab

Answer (score 3):

If is going to be executed on a cronjob, I'm assuming its in order to sync the dir.

In that case, I would use [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) to make an incremental backup. That way, only the things that change will transferred.

This system will use ssh for transferring the data, but using `rdiff-backup` instead of a plain `scp`. The major benefit of doing it this way is **speed**; is faster to transfer only the parts that have changed.

This is the command to do a copy over ssh using rdiff-backup:

```
rdiff-backup /some/local-dir hostname.net::/whatever/remote-dir
```

Add that to a cronjob, making sure the user that executes the rdiff backup has the ssh keys, so it does not require a password.

(**About ssh keys:** Read about ssh keys here: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html Once is set, try to do a regular ssh to see if you can log without password.)

Something like this:

```
* * * * * rdiff-backup /some/local-dir hostname.net::/whatever/remote-dir
```

will do the copy every minute. (your example, `1 * * * *` will execute every *first* minute of each hour; that is, once every hour, instead of once every minute)

Keep in mind that can cause problems if the transfer is huge it hasn't finished to transfer. But I guess that you want is to do transfers of not so huge files. Or that your network speed is large. Otherwise, change it to do the transfer every 5 minutes by using `*/5 * * * *` instead.

And finally, read more about rdiff-backup here : http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/examples.html

Comment: does rdiff-backup transfer deletions as well? I'm using `sftp` on a cronjob for a _one-way sync_, not a complete sync (actually, I'm backing up backup files), but I want to ensure a catastrophic wipeout won't propagate.

Comment: only good if you have ssh access to the other machine...

Comment: @Michel Yes. The question is talking about `sftp`, which is ftp over ssh, so it's assuming ssh access.

Answer (score 1):

rdiff-backup is a good option, there is also [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)

```
rsync -az user@10.10.10.123:/home/user/myfiles .
```

I notice you are also deleting files, is this simply because you don't want to recopy them? rsync will only copy updated files.

You might also be interested in [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) which does a two way sync

Answer (score 0):

These are both good answers; if you stick with `scp` you may want to make a slight change to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/scp -r user@10.10.10.123:/home/user/myfiles .
#REMOVE FILES AFTER ALL HAVE BEEN SENT
cd /home/user/myfiles   # make sure you're in the right directory before rm
rm -rf *
```