# How to download huge file in GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, guzzle

I have a code in PHP which hits an URL using Guzzle. The code works fine but, as the size of the .wbk file that I'm trying to download is close to 7 GB, it downloads around 500 - 600 MB of data and throws me an error.

This is the code that I'm using:

```js
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '10000M');
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 999999999);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 999999999);

use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\FileCookieJar;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

$jar = "These are the cookies set";

$download_wbk_file = $client->request('GET', 'URL_FROM_WHICH_I_WANT_TO_DOWNLOAD_THE_FILE', [
        'cookies' => $jar,
        'sink' => './Testfile.csv',
        'defaults' => [
            'stream' => true,
            'read_timeout' => 600, 
                    'timeout' => 10.0, 
            ]
    ]);
?>
```

This is the error that I'm getting:
[Guzzle timeout error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efa5D.png)

I've tried increasing the **read_timeout and timeout** parameters but, the error remains the same.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Have you considered using a different protocol for the file transfer? Maybe sftp?

Comment: @bassxzero No I haven't, This is a automation script that I'm intending to do without any manual intervention.

Comment: You can script sftp too.

Comment: @bassxzero can you please give me a link so that I can check if its feasible for my script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154998/cron-job-to-sftp-files-in-a-directory